# Char array printing extra garbage memory

Tags: c

This program is supposed to ouput `VYGHBUTMDE`, but it appends some garbage characters on the end.  Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
encrpypt(char ciphertext_buffer[], char plaintext[], char key[]) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++) {
    ciphertext_buffer[i] = (char) ( ( ((int)plaintext[i] - 65 + (int)key[i%(strlen(key))] - 65) % 26 ) + 65 );
  }
  return 0;
}

int
main() {
  char ciphertext_buffer[10];
  encrpypt(ciphertext_buffer, "THISISCOOL", "CRYPT");
  printf("%s\n", ciphertext_buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are only allocating a 10 byte array for a 10 byte string, there is "nowhere" for the terminating null character to go.  Consider increasing the buffer size to at least one character greater than the length of the string in "visible" characters.

Comment: Thanks :)  Been a while since I've programmed with C

Comment: No worries, friend!  I hope the explanation was sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are not null terminating the string. Here is a slightly modified version: (although there are still problems)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
encrpypt(char ciphertext_buffer[], char plaintext[], char key[]) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++) {
    ciphertext_buffer[i] = (char) ( ( ((int)plaintext[i] - 65 + (int)key[i%(strlen(key))] - 65) % 26 ) + 65 );
  }
  ciphertext_buffer[i] = 0;
  return 0;
}

int
main() {
  char ciphertext_buffer[11];
  encrpypt(ciphertext_buffer, "THISISCOOL", "CRYPT");
  printf("%s\n", ciphertext_buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

A larger problem is that you are not doing any bounds checking. Here is a better version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
encrpypt(char ciphertext_buffer[], char plaintext[], char key[], int size) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++) {
    if (i > size - 1) break;
    ciphertext_buffer[i] = (char) ( ( ((int)plaintext[i] - 65 + (int)key[i%(strlen(key))] - 65) % 26 ) + 65 );
  }
  ciphertext_buffer[i] = 0;
  return 0;
}

int
main() {
  char ciphertext_buffer[11];
  encrpypt(ciphertext_buffer, "THISISCOOL", "CRYPT", sizeof(ciphertext_buffer));
  printf("%s\n", ciphertext_buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Char array has to be terminated with '/0'. So always u need to allocate char array as max string size + 1.

try with below corrections.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int encrpypt(char ciphertext_buffer[], char plaintext[], char key[]) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++) {
    ciphertext_buffer[i] = (char) ( ( ((int)plaintext[i] - 65 + (int)key[i%(strlen(key))] - 65) % 26 ) + 65 );
  }
 ciphertext_buffer[i] = '\0';
  return 0;
}

int
main() {
  char ciphertext_buffer[11];
  encrpypt(ciphertext_buffer, "THISISCOOL", "CRYPT");
  printf("%s\n", ciphertext_buffer);
  return 0;
}
```